# How to use $(this) inside JS function and then find attr?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you use `$(this)` with a JS function and then find the `attr`?

```
 function date_box() {
   alert(this.getAttribute(week));
  }
```

I want to get the attribute `week` from an element called `gospel_table`4. On click of `gospel_table4`, the function is triggered:

```
<a href='#'><div id='gospel_table4' week='$one_date' onclick='date_box()'> Week $one_date </div></a>
```

I can't do this:

```
$(this).click...
```

Because only one element of `gospel_table4` is clickable. With the other method, all the elements of `gospel_table4` are clickable.

**Basicially, how do I get the attr from the function of date_box()?**

Comment: `onclick='date_box(this)'` then `function date_box(this) {
   alert($(this).attr('week'));
  }`

Comment: @guradio Doesn't work...

Comment: @guradio - You can't have a function argument called `this`.

Comment: *"I can't do this: `$(this).click...` Because only one element of gospel_table4 is clickable."* - I think you'll find that you *can* use jQuery to bind the click handler if you do it properly. But why are you making an element *inside* an anchor clickable? Normally anchors are clickable already, and a user who doesn't have a mouse will only be able to use their keyboard to "click" the *anchor*, not the div.

Comment: use `getAttributes` in `JAVASCRIPT`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a param inside your function

HTML:

```
<a href='#'><div id='gospel_table4' week='$one_date' onclick='date_box(this)'> Week $one_date </div></a>
```

Javascript:

```
function date_box(thisdiv){
   alert($(thisdiv).attr("week"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
function date_box(that)
{
   $attr=that.getAttribute('week');
  alert($attr);
}
```

```html
<a href='#'><div id='gospel_table4' week='$one_date' onclick='date_box(this)'> Week $one_date </div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

so the reason why click is not working is that div is inside anchor tag,
and anchor is clicked there are references like [Anchor tag becomes non-working link in a div with float: right;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777714/anchor-tag-becomes-non-working-link-in-a-div-with-float-right) or [Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct) which can give more details. So following is the code in jQuery()

```
$("#gospel_table4").parent("a").click(function(){
    var week = $(this).children("#gospel_table4").attr("week");
    console.log(week);
});
```

Explanation :  Since we know that anchor is clicked first we place the click event listener on anchor tag . Then we can access the relative child element.

This will work but date_box() will also be invoked at the same time, I would recommend that you remove the onclick and and place it in side the above that way you would have more control over the code. Hope this is helpful.